# What file(s) need editing to remove a wireless access point from wlp2s0?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

```
innocent / # nmcli d wifi list
*  SSID               MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
=========================================================================
   HillBillies        Infra  2     54 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA2

*  TELPorto           Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  76      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 

   NgNetHookup        Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

I only wish to keep `TELPorto`, `HillBillies` and `NgNetHookup` need to be nuked.
From reading `man nmcli`, I was unable to discover how to edit that list. I am running Linux Mint.

Issuing :
innocent / # iw wlp2s0 scan

one of the items is (in part) :

```
BSS f8:c3:9e:5d:2d:b8(on wlp2s0)

    TSF: 127000886994 usec (1d, 11:16:40)
    freq: 2417
    beacon interval: 100 TUs
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1411)
    signal: -50.00 dBm
    last seen: 2964 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: Ng WiFiLink
    (...)
    (...) /...
```

Issuing :
innocent / # nmcli -f all dev wifi list

returns output like so

```
SSID => Ng WiFiLink
SSID-HEX => 436975612057256961
BSSID => F8:C3:9E:5D:2D:B8
MODE => Infra
CHAN => 2
FREQ => 2417 MHz
RATE => 54 Mbit/s
SIGNAL => 90
BARS => ▂▄▆█
SECURITY => WPA2
WPA-FLAGS => pair_ccmp group_ccmp psk
RSN-FLAGS => wlp2s0
DEVICE  ACTIVE => [  ]   ( * if yes ?)
DBUS-PATH => /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/85
```

Issuing :
innocent / # nmcli -p -f general,wifi-properties device show wlp2s0

```
====================================================================
                            Device details (wlp2s0)
====================================================================
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
(...)
(...) /...
GENERAL.CON-UUID:             eb8ab8ea-e616-48ba-a9eb-a6bfdf1ec480
GENERAL.CON-PATH:      /org/freedesktopNetworkManagerActiveConnection/6
```

The following were just a few of the 20? or 30? *yug* combinatorial / experimenting efforts made to chance on some syntax nmcli would work with:

Trying using DBUS-PATH // GENERAL.CON-PATH:
innocent / # nmcli dev disconnect /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6

Error: Device '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/83' not found.

Error: not all devices found.

Trying using SSID-HEX:
innocent / # nmcli dev disconnect 436975612057256961

Error: Device '436975612057256961' not found.

Error: not all devices found.

Trying with UUID:

innocent system-connections # nmcli dev disconnect 'eb8ab8ea-e616-48ba-a9eb-a6bfdf1ec480'

Error: Device 'eb8ab8ea-e616-48ba-a9eb-a6bfdf1ec480' not found.

Error: not all devices found.

Finally, for the WIN, using one of the commands referenced in the
answer below, from GAD3R , this did the job:

innocent system-connections # nmcli connection delete id Ng\ WiFiLink

Connection 'Ng WiFiLink' (eb8ab8ea-e616-48ba-a9eb-a6bfdf1ec480) successfully deleted.
innocent system-connections #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `nmcli d wifi list` will list the available access point from the previous scan. You need to refresh the list of AP through:

```
nmcli device wifi rescan
```

Then:

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

`info nmcli`:

> ```
> wifi rescan [ifname ifname] [ssid SSID...]
>        Request that NetworkManager immediately re-scan for available
>        access points...
>
> This command does not show the APs, use nmcli device wifi list for that.
> ```

---

The saved configuration can be listed through:

```
nmcli connection
```

To remove a connection by its name:

```
nmcli connection delete id 'connection name'
```

To remove a connection by its UUID:

```
nmcli connection delete uuid 'connection uuid'
```

Comment: Seems like a good thing to check that an item was in fact deleted, but my question is where/how, to delete or permanently disable items there